# Change IMEI number to obtain tablet data plan?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, mobile-data, 4g, imei

It looks like T-Mobile offers very cheap data-only plans, but these are only available for tablets. I have read that this is enforced by tracking your IMEI. I was wondering: Is it possible to change your phone's IMEI to a tablet's IMEI, to trick T-Mobile, so that you can get a data-only plan. Nobody really needs talk and text if they have data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would undoubtedly be a violation of T-Mobile's terms of service.  To do so, though, you would need to create a custom ROM and modify the `ro.serialno` system property.  Alternatively you could try to modify Build.java and pass in a different value to Build.SERIAL.  It's unclear whether that's how T-Mobile is retrieving the IMEI number though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you are looking for, [[XPOSED] IMEI Changer & PRO [RANDOM IMEI Support]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xposed-imei-changer-t2847187)

You will need to [root](/questions/tagged/root)your phone and install [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

- The ways of [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) can be founded by clicking on theses tags linked or by googling your device model and how to root it.
- What is Xposed Framework For Android & How To Install It [[Guide]](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/what-is-xposed-framework-for-android-how-to-install-it-guide/)

---

**Keep in Mind** This is in violation of T-Mobiles Terms of Services

**Hopefully** I have linked you to all necessary stuff for you to be able to change your IMEI Number