# How to write IMEI programmatically on Pixel XL

Tags: rooting, google-pixel, imei

I have an unlocked Pixel XL device purchased recently.
I'd want to test changing IMEI of the device.
My final purpose is to randomize IMEI dynamically from a user space application.
Before this, I would like to check if IMEI writing basically works or not.

I've explored many communities and blogs for some days, but haven't found out working solution yet, even through fastboot.

For example,

```
fastboot oem writeimei 1234*****
```

is not working, but it keeps saying as if its unknown command !

Is there a way to change IMEI on Pixel XL unlocked?

Best

Comment: spoofing IMEI is illegal in some countries therefore most likely protected against changes. Nevertheless you should ask in a different wording (aka how to restore lost IMEI) because development is off-topic here

Comment: Thank you for advice. So do you have any workaround?

Comment: no. maybe interesting for you https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225881

Comment: Hi, @alecxs. Can I assume you are recommending AT commands? And if so, are you sure it will be definitely possible? Any examples running AT commands from user space apps would be much appreciated!

Comment: sorry if i knew it i would tell. for Mediatek there is [NVRAM](https://www.android.gs/backuprestore-imei-and-nvram-on-any-android-device) but HTC is qualcomm device. search on [youtube](https://youtu.be/m9hq-FiDn58) maybe you find something you can start with

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/134911